# Using nth of type or nth-child to target elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following code whereby I am trying to select one of the four .v-list__tile p elements depending upon what class the .v-list has attached to it but haven't been successful in using nth-child or nth-of-type correctly to target the first element I want. This is the markup:

```
<div role="list" class="v-list theme--light price">
  <div role="listitem">
    <div class="v-list__tile theme--light">
      <p><strong>Price</strong></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div role="listitem">
    <div class="v-list__tile theme--light">
      <p><strong>Timing</strong></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="listitem">
    <div class="v-list__tile theme--light">
      <p><strong>Options</strong></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="listitem">
   <div class="v-list__tile theme--light">
    <p><strong>Review/Submit</strong></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

If the .v-list has a class of "price", I want **only the first** .v-list__tile p element to have styling attached to it. If the .v-list has a class of "timing", I want **only the second** .v-list__tile p element to have styling attached to it. Here's where I'm confused: I am actually able to select everything *except* the first p element with nth-child, but selecting the first child or nth-child(1) adds styling to *all* of the p elements instead of just the first one.

```
.price div:nth-child(1) p{
   border-bottom:1px solid #009FD4; //doesn't work- selects *all* p elements//
 } 
.timing div:nth-child(2) p{
   border-bottom:1px solid #009FD4; //works- selects only the second p element//
 }
.options div:nth-child(3) p{
   border-bottom:1px solid #009FD4; //works- selects only the third p element//
 }
.review div:nth-child4) p{
   border-bottom:1px solid #009FD4; //works- selects only the fourth p element//
 }
```

How can I write out some css to target only the first .v-list__tile p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling css to find all divs inside the main div **.price**. And because all your divs inside **.price** contain another child div (**v-list__tile**) there is always a first div. When you target a 2nd or 3rd child, because there is no 2nd nor 3rd divs inside the divs with role: **listitem** then it all seems to work (but it's not). It was just chance that your structure was this one and that you had not more than one div at the end of your structure.
You will be able to achieve want you want If you target only the direct descender:

```
.price > div:nth-child(1) p{
   border:1px solid #009FD4; 
 }
```

I hope this helps: https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

> The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent.

That means your first line will apply to all of your elements.

You could use this instead

```
.price .v-list__tile:first-child p {
    border:1px solid #009FD4;
}
```